# Move UITextView caret to new line when user enter 29 character?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

i want only 3 lines in UITextView. And each line will have maximum 29 characters

What i did is

```
 static const NSUInteger MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES_ALLOWED = 3;

        NSMutableString *t = [NSMutableString stringWithString: self.addressTextView.text];
        [t replaceCharactersInRange: range withString: text];

        NSUInteger numberOfLines = 0;
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            if ([[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember: [t characterAtIndex: i]]) {
                numberOfLines++;
            }
        }

        return (numberOfLines < MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES_ALLOWED);
```

In below delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

Please let me know that how i can restrict length of each line to max 29 characters.

That is if user type 29 characters in first line then take him to newline.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475670/every-new-line-add-a-numbered-list-uitextview

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right. You need implement next few lines in shouldChangeTextInRange: method.

```
if (range. location%29==0) {
//add new line
}
```

I hope, it will help you!